# Gradle does not add resources to module path

Tags: intellij-idea, gradle, log4j2, java-9, java-module

I created a [simple gradle project](https://github.com/pandrez/jigsaw-gradle) that builds and runs a simple java 9 module.

This module requires only log4j and expects to find a log4j2.xml file to configure the logger.

The problem I am having is that it seems that this file is not added to the module classpath and when I execute`./gradlew run` I always get *"ERROR StatusLogger No log4j2 configuration file found. Using default configuration:"* as the first output line, which means it could not find the file (which is under src/main/resources).

If I import this project in IntelliJ and run it, I get the exact same error.

Am I doing something wrong? Shouldn't this file be automatically added to the module classpath?

Comment: Related [log4j2 configuration file not found with java 9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46138895/log4j2-configuration-file-not-found-with-java-9)

Comment: Thank you for the heads up! I believe the problem lies in gradle.