# Getting error "module not found": log4j.core while running application on Java 9

Tags: java, maven

> [INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
>
> [ERROR]
>
> /C:/Users/sumit.garg/workspace_oxy_java9/csp-shared/src/main/java/module-info.java:[9,27]
>   module not found: log4j.core [ERROR]
>
> /C:/Users/sumit.garg/workspace_oxy_java9/csp-shared/src/main/java/module-info.java:[10,26]
>   module not found: log4j.api

Here is my `module-info.java`. It is compiled without error.

```
module cspSharedModule {
    requires log4j.core;
    requires log4j.api;
    requires java.xml;
    requires java.xml.bind;
}
```

maven-compiler-plugin:

```
        <plugin>
           <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
           <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
           <version>3.8.0</version>
           <configuration>
               <source>9</source>
               <target>9</target>
               <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
               <showDeprecation>true</showDeprecation>
           </configuration>
       </plugin>
```

Comment: hi, this might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46140686/1004631

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Module not found: How to compile JDK 10 Eclipse Maven Project with Module?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50621741/module-not-found-how-to-compile-jdk-10-eclipse-maven-project-with-module)

Comment: @robot_alien thanks